# Combining two lists of strings together once in Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, string, list, loops, zip

I'm trying to combine a list of first- and surnames with no luck. My code is like this at the moment:

```
firstname=['Tom','Dick','Steve']
surname=['Johnson','Smith','Doe']
for f in (firstname):
    for s in (surname):
        print(f,s)
```

Which gives me something like this:

```
Tom Johnson
Tom Smith
Tom Doe
Dick Johnson
```

And so on, when I really want:

```
Tom Johnson
Dick Smith
Steve Doe
```

Help much appreciated for a beginner like me.

Comment: just zip lists together

Comment: That alone won't give him the output in the specified format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for name, surname in zip(firstname, surname):
   print(name, surname)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works wonderfully. Is it possible to iterate backwards as well using zip?

Comment: @Matsern Use `reverse` for reversing, but you need a sequence for that, whereas `zip` returns an iterator. So first consume the iterator into a list and then call `reverse`: `reversed(list(zip(firstname, surname)))`.

Comment: You can use while loops which is too old fashioned but you can control (print) elements in list in different ways since you were talking about reverse. Thanks!!

Comment: @ThijsvanDien thank you for your answer, but I found that

    zip(name, reversed(surname))

worked best in my case. Just leaving this for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

Zip is the way to combine two lists together in python. So, as a function,

```
def combine_names(first, last):
    comb = zip(first, last)
    for f,l in comb:
        print f,l
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both lists have the same length, you could iterate over it and use the corresponding index on both:

```
for i in range(len(firstname)):
    print (firstname[i], surname[i])
```

Comment: This is not the Pythonic way to do it - that is what "zip" is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
firstname=['Tom','Dick','Steve']
surname=['Johnson','Smith','Doe']
i = 0
while i<min(len(firstname), len(surname)):
    print (firstname[i], surname[j])
    i += 1
```

Comment: Why so terribly low level?

Comment: @ThijsvanDien Yeah its very old fashioned, from his question, he is missing a fundamental concept of nested loop. And I'm guessing he is new to programming. So posted this classic and mechanical while loop :)

Comment: I appreciate your intentions, but I find this code rather confusing to be honest. The lists are equally long; (and even if they weren't) why use two loops at all? The outer loop in your example doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have updated. I removed outer while, since the length of lists remain equal, I guess this wont be a problem. Is it too confusing? do you want me to delete this answer?

Comment: Since `i` and `j` are always equal, you can stick to just `i`. To account for possible differences in length, you might use `while i < min(len(firstname), len(surname))`. But then you might as well use a `for` loop. And then you might as well drop the indices completely... You see where this leads to. I don't mind different implementations, but really in this case it is unnecessary complication. I'm not sure how much that helps the OP.